# Dot net application unable to handle more 5000 records

Tags: performance, optimization, graph, ssis

we are working on a .net desktop application. On the GUI, there are number of tabs and panels. graph tab, imges tab, result grid tab etc. The task is to fetch about 50,000 records and be able to take its different views. e.g can have graph amoung two columns, can go throug the results in the grid and can view images of the records.

Application is developed but its performence is too bad. We are trying to target it atleast for **50,000** records, but its response gets weired on about 5000 records.

**Facts:**

1- Queryies are complex which include number on joins. On the avg 10 to 12 tables joins. And sometimes subquery table as join. It takes about 8 to 10 seconds to return results.
   What can be done to achive performance at this level.
    - Index are used properly.

Can using SSIS (Sql Server Integration Services) help in the context?

2- Graphs support very less amount of data and start getting exshast on about 4000 records. What can be done to improve graph's performance?

Pagging can't be used when graphs are involve.

Comment: could you post table schema and sample query?

Comment: Are you using stored procedures to perform your complex queries, table joins and data handling so that your .NET application only needs to call it?

Comment: If it takes 8 to 10 seconds to retrieve the rows from something like SSMS or sqlcmd, then you could expect SSIS to take a similar time-frame to return the data. Instead, I'd focus on improving your queries and potentially restructuring your tables.

Answer (score 1):

Please post your schema and a sample query so that it can be improved upon.

As for the graph performance, here's some general performance tips (assuming WinForms):

Does  the graph object have a `.BeginUpdate()` or `.BeginDataUpdate()` and a corresponding `.EndUpdate()` / `.EndDataUpdate()` method? If it has those then you should be using that. The same applies to the GridControl as well.

Are you adding the items to the graph/grid (or their datasource) one by one, or are you calling `.AddRange()` or setting the `data source` / `data bindings`. If you're adding the adding the items one by one then it will often remake the list over and over, this was a common problem with the .NET 1.1 `ListView` control, because the items underneath were stored in an array and each `.Add(..)` call recreated the array so it very quickly went `O(n^2)` for adding items.

What graphing and grid controls are you using?